# Test in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testing, web

Can you help me please?

During a test, I did not understand this question:

> Given the following code, write two lines of JavaScript to call the
>   `print()` function in a way that prints the Window global object in the
>   JavaScript console?
>
> Your code must not use the variable `window`. Feel free to comment.
>
> ```
> Printer = function(){
>     this.print = function() {
>        console.log(this);
>     }
> }
> var printer = new Printer();
> ```

Comment: Please be more specific...what don't you understand? We aren't mind readers. Now would be a good time to read through [ask] and [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I did not understand how to do this : call the print() function in a way that prints the Window global object without use the variable window.

Comment: Try `printer.print.call(this)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
Could you explain this code, please?

Comment: In global namespace (in browser) `this` is `window`...you can look up `call()` yourself

Comment: I am sorry to ask these simple questions.
Thank you for everything.

I don't understand the usefulness of the question asked during the test.
Why used the function call on a function instead of doing console.log (this) ?

Comment: Ask the person who created the test. Would seem they wanted to assess your higher level knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
printer.print.call(this);
//or
printer.print.bind(this)();
```

Why this is usefull:

Example: adding an event listener in an object:

```
function person(){
this.clicker=0;
document.body.addEventListener("click",function(){
this.clicker++;
});
}
```

So this should work, shouldnt it? Nope it doesnt, cause the eventlistener automatically binds this as the clicked element. So this will be body, wich hasnt a clicker property. So in that situation its usefull to override this...

```
 document.body.addEventListener("click",function(){
this.clicker++;
}.bind(this))
```

Or in newer browsers (see arrow funcs):

```
 document.onclick=()=>{
 this.clicker++;
 };
```

Thats what the tutorial wants to tell you. Hope it helps...